# How can I see all files which are sourced for an environment variable?

Tags: bash, environment-variables, path

For example, I would like to see all files that are setting `$PATH`.  For some terminals, this could be trivial, but I'm troubleshooting my terminal and having a hard time finding every file where this variable is set.

Answer (score 0):

From bash manpage:

> /etc/profile
>            The systemwide initialization file, executed for login shells
>
> /etc/bash.bashrc
>            The systemwide per-interactive-shell startup file
>
> ~/.bash_profile
>            The personal initialization file, executed for login shells
>
> ~/.bashrc
>            The individual per-interactive-shell startup file

So you can read from there who modify yout `PATH`. Note: you should follow also the `source` and `.` build-in (which includes other files).

Comment: Hi, I am new to unix so I am not entirely sure what you are suggesting with source and . build in.  I am familiar with both of these commands but I have used them imperatively, eg 'source ~/.bash_profile'. what do you mean to follow them? where can i find which files they include? Thank you